# → LSN1-der ____ ←

Tags: wordplay

> → LSN1-der ____ ←

What’s to be placed at the underscores?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to guess the answer is

> land

because

> it's a [rebus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus) for "Alice in Wonderland" (LS N 1-der land).